# .htaccess remove index.php/url/ from URL

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

.htaccess is not working.

- `/index.php/user` -- is working
- `http://www.example.com/user` is not working

Current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: What is "lease web hosting?" Is mod_rewrite even installed/active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check httpd.conf to see if [.htaccess is enabled](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/403218-apache2-htaccess-how-enable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rules should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

If your CI installation runs on a CGI implementation, you should add a questionmark in the .htaccess, lik so:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: its not working.same problem again'

Comment: Then you have to come up with more information than 'is working, is not working' How do you determine that it doesn't work? Have you checked your error logs? Does it even work without the mod_rewrite rules? Did you setup the config.php correctly?